# Subquery in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below code creates a table in SQL server with keeps track of annual certifications my clients must submit on an annual basis. The certification is submitted after the calendar year (2018, 2019, etc.) has concluded. I need a query that, for each client, yields the date when the annual certification for the most recent calendar year was received, along with the calendar year for which the certification was intended. Some of my clients are lagers and they may submit an certification for a past year after certifications for most recent years have been received. The following table shows the intended results. I would like to employee one single query. The below query at the end of my code, intended for this situation, does not work. What am I missing here? Thanks.

These are the intended results:

```
CLIENT_ID DATE_RECEIVED CERTIFICATION_YEAR

1         2019-01-02    2018

2         2020-01-07    2019

3         2021-01-10    2020
```

Sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CERTIFICATION](
    [CERTIFICATION_ID] [numeric](11, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CLIENT_ID] [numeric](11, 0) NOT NULL,
    [DATE_RECEIVED] [date] NOT NULL,
    [CERTIFICATION_YEAR] [numeric](4, 0) NOT NULL,
    
    
 CONSTRAINT [CERTIFICATION_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CERTIFICATION_ID] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

DECLARE @YEAR_COUNTER int
DECLARE @YEAR_INC int

SET @YEAR_COUNTER = 2014
SET @YEAR_INC = 1

WHILE @YEAR_COUNTER <= 2018

BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CERTIFICATION] (CLIENT_ID, DATE_RECEIVED, CERTIFICATION_YEAR)
VALUES (1, DATEADD(year, @YEAR_INC, '1-02-2014'),@YEAR_COUNTER)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CERTIFICATION] (CLIENT_ID, DATE_RECEIVED, CERTIFICATION_YEAR)
VALUES (2, DATEADD(year, @YEAR_INC, '1-07-2015'),@YEAR_COUNTER+1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CERTIFICATION] (CLIENT_ID, DATE_RECEIVED, CERTIFICATION_YEAR)
VALUES (3, DATEADD(year, @YEAR_INC, '1-10-2016'),@YEAR_COUNTER+2)

SET @YEAR_COUNTER = @YEAR_COUNTER + 1
SET @YEAR_INC = @YEAR_INC + 1

END 

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CERTIFICATION] (CLIENT_ID, DATE_RECEIVED, CERTIFICATION_YEAR)
VALUES (1, '2-2-2020',2013)

GO
```

The below query will trigger an error. If the third column of the query is removed, the query will work but it will only retrieve the last year for which a certification was submitted.

```
SELECT        CERTIFICATION_ID, MAX(CERTIFICATION_YEAR) AS LAST_CERTIFICATION_YEAR,
                             (SELECT        DATE_RECEIVED
                               FROM            dbo.CERTIFICATION AS CERT
                               WHERE        (CLIENT_ID = dbo.CERTIFICATION.CLIENT_ID) AND (CERTIFICATION_YEAR = dbo.CERTIFICATION.CERTIFICATION_YEAR)) AS LAST_CERTIFICATION_DATE
FROM            dbo.CERTIFICATION
GROUP BY CERTIFICATION_ID
```

Comment: CAn you please share an example of your desired results. What would that result set look like?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the error message that it gives you.

Comment: That sub-select looks extraneous. Whet happens if you just put DATE_RECEIVED in the main selection list? Since CERTIFICATION_ID is the primary key, the group by is really not needed (it is unique per row), and thus the MAX isn't needed either. Try it with those changes...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want a single query like this one:

```
SELECT
    C.CLIENT_ID,
    C.DATE_RECEIVED,
    C.CERTIFICATION_YEAR
FROM
    dbo.CERTIFICATION C
WHERE
    C.CERTIFICATION_YEAR =
    (SELECT MAX(D.CERTIFICATION_YEAR) FROM dbo.CERTIFICATION D WHERE C.CLIENT_ID = D.CLIENT_ID)
```

Comment: Tamora's answer is what I was looking for (Thanks Tamora!). But I can't understand why the sub-select triggers an error. The syntax is correct.

Comment: @fritesmodern please add the actual error message to your question.